# Cannot find symbol compile error when adding print statement

Tags: java, class, printing

I have a file with a list of names their sex and the count of how many people have the name .What I am trying to do is separate the males from the females and put the top 3 females and males by descending order. Everything compiles until I try to print then I get a "cannot find symbol error".

**file:**

Mary F 13173

John M 6990

William M 6086

Anna F 5115

Helen F 5048

James M 4598

Margaret F 4249

George M 4018

Ruth F 3912

Florence F 3314

**What i am trying to get:**

John M 6990

William M 6086

James M 4598

Mary F 13173

Anna F 5115

Helen F 5048

```
public List<String> descending()
{
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    Collections.sort(oneName, new OneNameCountCompare());
    for(OneName b: oneName)
    {
        x.add(b.toString());
        if (x.size() == 10) // Or don't use enhanced for, use an index instead
    {
        break;
    }
}
return x;
}
```

---

```
String top(int many, char sex)
{
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0 ;i < many;i++)
    {
        if(sex == oneName.get(i).getSex())
        {
          answer = oneName.get(i).getName();
        }

    }
    return answer; 
 }
```

---

```
String maleTop = top(3, 'M');
String femaleTop = top(3, 'F');
System.out.println(maleTop.descending());
System.out.println(femaleTop.descending());
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the `cannot find symbol error`?

Comment: the System.out.println(maleTop.descending()); and System.out.println(femaleTop.descending()); lines

Comment: Are you trying to call `descending()` method on a `String` object? i.e. `maleTop.descending()`

Comment: So how should i be calling it?

Comment: Does java `String` have a `descending()` method? Confirm this by looking at Oracle's Java API doc online. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/